# Math -not getting result when less than 1

Tags: java, android, math

I have a math problem. actually it is a really simple one, but for some reason I can't get a simple math action to show inside a `TextView`.

I want to show the user knowledge so I entered values from calculation into a `double`. Then tried getting it into a `TextView` by using `Double.toString`..
the code is

```
double knoledgePercentage = ((100/(endingPoint - startingPoint))*knownCount);
    tv.setText(Double.toString(knoledgePercentage));
```

the thing is that I even tried doing the math with number, to see that the variables is ok. id did like this:

```
double knoledgePercentage = ((100/400)*3);
    tv.setText(Double.toString(knoledgePercentage));
```

and still it shows 0.0 in the `TextView`.
**just to be clear** my problem is not with using the `TextView` but with doing the math.

Answer (score 4):

You are using integer division in Java, which truncates any decimal, because an `int` divided by an `int` must still yield an `int`.  So, `100/400` is `0` in Java, not `0.25`.  Only then is it assigned to a `double` and promoted to a `double`, `0.0`.

Cast one of the literals into a `double` or use `double` literals to force floating-point math.

```
double knoledgePercentage = (((double) 100/400)*3);
```

or

```
double knoledgePercentage = ((100.0/400)*3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Worked like a charm